# Jacobi's Rotation has two possibilities, why do they both result in same upper triangular magnitude norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The Jacobi's rotation is the complex Givens rotation (unitary similarity) that results in a zero for a specified element of a matrix. If the element 
is not adjacent to the diagonal, then there are rows/columns below the diagonal that mix with rows/columns above the diagonal.
Here is the general form (where eventually $x$ will be the element to zero):

\begin{align}
&
   \pmatrix{c               & \mathbf{0} & s \\
            \mathbf{0}^\top & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0}^\top \\
            -\bar{s}        & \mathbf{0} & \bar{c} \\
   }
   \pmatrix{d_0             & \mathbf{g} & x \\
            \mathbf{a}^\top & \mathbf{D} & \mathbf{b}^\top \\
            y               & \mathbf{h} & d_1 \\
   }
   \pmatrix{\bar{c}         & \mathbf{0} & -s \\
            \mathbf{0}^\top & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0}^\top \\
            \bar{s}        & \mathbf{0} & c \\
   }
\\
=&
   \pmatrix{c               & \mathbf{0} & s \\
            \mathbf{0}^\top & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0}^\top \\
            -\bar{s}        & \mathbf{0} & \bar{c} \\
   }
   \pmatrix{d_0\bar{c}+x\bar{s}   & \mathbf{g} & -d_0 s + x c \\
            \mathbf{a}^\top\bar{c} + \mathbf{b}^\top\bar{s}& \mathbf{D} & -\mathbf{a}^\top s + \mathbf{b}^\top c \\
            y \bar{c} + d_1 \bar{s}              & \mathbf{h} & -y s + d_1 c \\
   }
\\
=&
   \pmatrix{d_0c\bar{c} + d_1s\bar{s} + c\bar{s}x + \bar{c}sy  & c\mathbf{g}+ s\mathbf{h}                & (d_1 - d_0)cs + x c^2 - ys^2 \\
            \mathbf{a}^\top \bar{c} + \mathbf{b}^\top \bar{s}  &        \mathbf{D}                       & -\mathbf{a}^\top s + \mathbf{b}^\top c \\
            (d_1 -d_0)\bar{c}\bar{s} -x\bar{s}^2 + y\bar{c}^2  & -\bar{s}\mathbf{g} + \bar{c}\mathbf{h}  & d_0s\bar{s} + d_1c\bar{c} - c\bar{s}x - \bar{c}sy
   }
\end{align}

Specifically $\mathbf{g} \leftarrow c\mathbf{g}+ s\mathbf{h}$, so that row vector $\mathbf{g}$ is mixed with row vector $\mathbf{h}$.

Now solving for $c$ and $s$ in the complex numbers that give $x \leftarrow 0$ results in two solutions. Both of which end with the same magnitude in the upper triangular portion
$$\Vert \mathbf{g} \Vert^2 + \Vert \mathbf{b} \Vert^2 \quad\text{is same for both solutions that give $x=0$}$$

I have yet to find the formulation that shows this, but multiple experimentation has yet to fail.

**EDIT** I have made a silly mistake in that all tests were done on *Hermitian* matrices. Now I guess I solved my question, but any discussions or error corrections are welcome...

Here is the formula for the rotation:

\begin{align}
  \delta &= d_1 - d_0 \\
  \Delta &= \pm\sqrt{\delta^2 + 4xy} \\
  k^2 &= \delta\bar{\delta} + \delta\bar{\Delta} + \bar{\delta}\Delta + \Delta\bar{\Delta} +4y\bar{y}\\
  c & = \frac{2y}{k} \\
  s & = \frac{\delta + \Delta}{k} \\
\end{align}

The following is the derivation.

---

Using $d_1 - d_0 = \delta$, the top right element is desired to be zero

$$\delta cs + x c^2 - ys^2 = 0$$

Use the substitution $$\alpha = \frac{s}{c}$$ then
\begin{align}
  \delta c^2\alpha + x c^2 - y\alpha^2c^2 = c^2\left(\delta\alpha + x - y\alpha^2\right) = 0
\end{align}

The equation $\delta\alpha + x - y\alpha^2=0$ is easily solved using the quadratic formula:
$$ \alpha = \frac{-\delta \pm \sqrt{\delta^2 - 4(-y)x}}{2(-y)} = \frac{\delta \mp \sqrt{\delta^2 + 4xy}}{2y} = \frac{k\cdot s}{k\cdot c}$$
Here $k$ is the real and non-zero scale factor that gives $c\bar{c} + s\bar{s} = 1$.

Denote $\Delta = \pm\sqrt{\delta^2 + 4xy}$.  Then we have
\begin{align}
  c &= \frac{2y}{k} \\
  s &= \frac{\delta+\Delta}{k} \\
  s\bar{s} + c\bar{c} &= \frac{(\delta+\Delta)(\bar{\delta} + \bar{\Delta}) + 4y\bar{y}}{k^2} = 1 \\
  \Rightarrow k^2 &= \delta\bar{\delta} + \delta\bar{\Delta} + \bar{\delta}\Delta + \Delta\bar{\Delta} +4y\bar{y}\\
\end{align}
This formulation gives the desired results for both $\pm\Delta$ (as is confirmed with computations).

Now looking at the magnitude $\Vert c\mathbf{g}+ s\mathbf{h} \Vert^2 + \Vert  c\mathbf{b}  -s\mathbf{a} \Vert^2$ we have

\begin{align}
  \Vert c\mathbf{g}+ s\mathbf{h} \Vert^2 + \Vert c\mathbf{b}  -s\mathbf{a} \Vert^2  = & (c\mathbf{g}+ s\mathbf{h} )(\bar{\mathbf{g}}^\top \bar{c}+ \bar{\mathbf{h}}^\top\bar{s}) \\
  & + (c\mathbf{b} - s\mathbf{a} )(\bar{\mathbf{b}}^\top \bar{c} - \bar{\mathbf{a}}^\top\bar{s})\\
  = & c\bar{c}\mathbf{g}\bar{\mathbf{g}}^\top + s\bar{s}\mathbf{h}\bar{\mathbf{h}}^\top + \bar{c}s\mathbf{h}\bar{\mathbf{g}}^\top + c\bar{s}\mathbf{g}\bar{\mathbf{h}}^\top\\
  & + c\bar{c}\mathbf{b}\bar{\mathbf{b}}^\top + s\bar{s}\mathbf{a}\bar{\mathbf{a}}^\top - \bar{c}s\mathbf{a}\bar{\mathbf{b}}^\top - c\bar{s}\mathbf{b}\bar{\mathbf{a}}^\top \\
  = & c\bar{c}(\underbrace{\mathbf{g}\bar{\mathbf{g}}^\top + \mathbf{b}\bar{\mathbf{b}}^\top}_{\omega}) + s\bar{s}(\underbrace{\mathbf{h}\bar{\mathbf{h}}^\top + \mathbf{a}\bar{\mathbf{a}}^\top}_{\theta}) + \bar{c}s(\underbrace{\mathbf{h}\bar{\mathbf{g}}^\top - \mathbf{a}\bar{\mathbf{b}}^\top}_{\mu}) + c\bar{s}(\underbrace{\mathbf{g}\bar{\mathbf{h}}^\top - \mathbf{b}\bar{\mathbf{a}}^\top}_{\bar{\mu}}) \\
  = & c\bar{c}\omega + s\bar{s}\theta + \bar{c}s\mu + c\bar{s}\bar{\mu}
\end{align}

EXPERIMENT SHOWS that this magnitude is constant with choice of $\pm\Delta$

What is even more confounding to me is that when $x=0$ is true already, and the non trivial rotation that retains the zero is performed, in *THAT* case
the magnitude does indeed change. Yet should it not be the same if the two choices from the original position of $x \ne 0$ give no change?

---

The non-trivial rotation that retains the zero (and which actually gives a diagonal swap $d_0 \leftrightarrow d_1$ and $y \leftarrow \bar{y}$):
\begin{align}
  \delta cs + x c^2 - ys^2 &= s(\delta c + 0 - ys) = 0\\
 \Rightarrow \frac{k\cdot s}{k\cdot c} &= \frac{\delta}{y} \\
 c & = \frac{y}{k} \\
 s & = \frac{\delta}{k} \\
 k^2 & = y\bar{y} + \delta\bar{\delta} \\
\end{align}

The magnitude $c\bar{c}\omega + s\bar{s}\theta + \bar{c}s\mu + c\bar{s}\bar{\mu}$ then is
$$\frac{y\bar{y}\omega + \delta\bar{\delta}\theta + \bar{y}\delta\mu + y\bar{\delta}\bar{\mu}}{k^2} =
\frac{y\bar{y}\omega + \delta\bar{\delta}\theta + \bar{y}\delta\mu + y\bar{\delta}\bar{\mu}}{y\bar{y} + \delta\bar{\delta}}$$

The change in the upper triangular norm then is

\begin{align}
  & \frac{y\bar{y}\omega + \delta\bar{\delta}\theta + \bar{y}\delta\mu + y\bar{\delta}\bar{\mu}}{y\bar{y} + \delta\bar{\delta}} - \omega \\
  = & \frac{y\bar{y}\omega + \delta\bar{\delta}\theta + \bar{y}\delta\mu + y\bar{\delta}\bar{\mu}-\omega(y\bar{y} + \delta\bar{\delta})}{y\bar{y} + \delta\bar{\delta}} =\frac{N}{D}\\
  N = & y\bar{y}\omega + \delta\bar{\delta}\theta + \bar{y}\delta\mu + y\bar{\delta}\bar{\mu}-\omega y\bar{y} -\omega \delta\bar{\delta}\\
   = & \delta\bar{\delta}\theta + \bar{y}\delta\mu + y\bar{\delta}\bar{\mu} -\omega \delta\bar{\delta}\\
   = & \delta\bar{\delta}(\theta - \omega) + \bar{y}\delta\mu + y\bar{\delta}\bar{\mu} \\
\end{align}