# orthogonal similarity transformation of diagonal matrix with pairwise different elements into matrix with identical elements on diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

In a derivation I encountered the following problem: Let $\mathbf{U}$ be an orthogonal matrix and $\mathbf{D}$ be a diagonal matrix with pairwise different, strictly positive elements, both of dimension $n$. An orthogonal similarity transformation $\mathbf{U^T} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{M}$ turns $\mathbf{D}$ into a matrix $\mathbf{M}$ which has **diagonal elements that are identical to each other** (but is not necessarily a diagonal matrix [actually there would be no solution for diagonal $\mathbf{M}$]).

How can I determine an orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{U}$ which fulfills this condition?

Is it always possible to find such a matrix $\mathbf{U}$, regardless of the dimension $n$ and regardless of the choice of diagonal elements in $\mathbf{D}$?

There is a related question, but it only concerns $2 \times 2$ matrices: [Is there a similarity transformation rendering all diagonal elements of a matrix equal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72144/702757)

Any ideas on this one? Thank you!

Comment: Are you allowing $U$ to be the identity matrix? What about if $U$ is a permutation matrix?

Comment: If $\mathbf{U}$ would be an identity matrix, $\mathbf{M}$ would be identical to $\mathbf{D}$, so its diagonal elements would not be identical. If $\mathbf{U}$ would be a permutation matrix, $\mathbf{M}$ would be diagonal and contain the same elements as $\mathbf{D}$, but in permuted order, so again the diagonal elements are not identical (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3362592/702757). By the way, $\mathbf{M}$ can't be diagonal since a similarity transformation preserves the eigenvalues and therefore the diagonal elements on diagonal matrices.

Comment: Ah, I see, there may be a misunderstanding: All diagonal elements of $\mathbf{M}$ should be identical **to each other**, not to the elements of $\mathbf{D}$. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: what's the field here, $\mathbb R$?  You *can* do this over reals though it takes a little work and is indirect. As is often the case, if you instead work over $\mathbb C$ and instead of orthogonal use the term unitary $\mathbf U$, so $\mathbf U^* \mathbf D \mathbf U =\mathbf M$, there is an extremely short and nice proof.

Comment: @user8675309: The field is the real numbers, but I would be very much interested to see the proof for the complex case. Could you be so kind and post it as an answer, thanks a lot! If you even know how to do it over reals, and find the time to post it as well, that would be even better. Looking forward to see your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the complex/unitary case, consider setting
$\mathbf U := \mathbf F$

where $\mathbf F$ is the Discrete Fourier Transform matrix, which is unitary. (The conventions vary -- sometimes people write $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathbf F$ as being unitary.) Then $\mathbf {FDF}^*$ is a circulant matrix and has constant elements on the diagonal.

in particular check, using associativity and outerproduct interpretation of matrix multiplication:
$\mathbf {FDF}^* =\big(\mathbf {FD}\big)\mathbf F^* = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\cdot \mathbf f_j \mathbf f_j^* $

and the diagonal of each $\mathbf f_j \mathbf f_j^*$ is constant.  Using the Hadamard product this is written as :
$\mathbf I\circ\big(\mathbf f_j \mathbf f_j^*\big)=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf I$

which gives the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll need some time to fully understand this. Just one question: The $\lambda_j$ is not meant to be an eigenvalue, but just a diagonal element of $\mathbf{D}$, right?

Comment: In the case of a diagonal matrix, they are the same.  I could have written $d_{j,j}$ instead.

Comment: I tested some products $\mathbf{f}_j\mathbf{f}_j^*$ from the examples given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix and it seems to work: the diagonal of the (complex) outer product has the same elements. How did you find out about this property?

Comment: Just for others who might be interested: $\mathbf{F}_{jk} = \exp\{2\pi i (j-1)(k-1)/n\}$ for $j,k=1,\ldots,n$ and $i^2=-1$, so $\mathbf{F}_{jk} \mathbf{F}_{jk}^* = \exp\{2\pi i (j-1)(k-1)/n\} \exp\{-2\pi i (j-1)(k-1)/n\} = \exp\{0\}= 1$, thus $\operatorname{diag}\{\mathbf{f}_j\mathbf{f}_j^*\} = \mathbf{1}$.

Comment: I was too slow for an edit: I omitted the factor $1/\sqrt{n}$ in the equations above.

Comment: I just noticed that for the real case, Hadamard matrices (with a factor $1/n$) fulfill the desired property. However, they are not available for all matrix sizes and apparently it is not even clear for which sizes they exist (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix). I also wonder whether the condition $\operatorname{diag}\{\mathbf{u}_j\mathbf{u}_j^T\} = \mathbf{1}$ is always required to fulfill the desired property or whether the property could be obtained only after the addition of all outer vector products.

Comment: right-- ignoring rescaling by a positive constant, the 2x2 Hadamard matrix $H_2$ is a DFT.  Then for dimensions of $2^m$ x $2^m$ you can easily get the result in reals via Kronecker products of $H_2$. The underlying idea is that the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix majorize the diagonal of said matrix, then (assuming no periodicity issues) passing a limit on the doubly stochastic matrix that relates the two, and then working backwards. None of that is needed per se -- the circulant matrix is a very common and useful matrix, so you could also get to this result by pattern recognition.

Comment: I get the part on the Hadamard matrices, but could I kindly ask you to elaborate on the rest of your comment ("The underlying idea ... pattern recognition.")? This remained opaque to me. Maybe add a separate answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a correction of my own comment: I think with the Hadamard matrices, the factor should be $1/\sqrt{n}$.